# vertically center stretched image in banner div

Tags: html, css, image, center, banner

I try to achieve the following with plain (x)html and CSS:

I have a website, that displays a banner image atop of the contents.
The image is situated in two nested divs.

I want to poroportionally stretch the image to the full page width.
From the image only the middle stipe of 150px height shall be visible.

Have a look at the image:

the black box represents the visible area of the page. The image is proportionally stretched to fit the page width, upper and lower area (opaque) shall be cut.
[image]

The code structure is as follows:

```
....
<body>
  ...
  <div class="someclass">
  ... <!-- several nested divs here -->
        <div id="outer">
          <div id="inner">
            <img src="tux.png" />
          </div>
        </div>
  ....
  </div>
  ...
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JQ4wp/2

I fiddled around some days, but was not able to achieve this. I found solutions putting the image in background, but this is not an option, since the code is generated by a CMS.

Could you help me?

thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle? or show the css?

Comment: `img { width: 100%; height: auto; }` ?

Comment: Does the image need to be there as an img, or could you use CSS background, with background-size/background-position goodness?

Comment: added note: image can not be used as background, since the code is created by a CMS.

Comment: can you align it with table, table-cell and vertical height/

Comment: Is javascript allowed?

Comment: it's not strictly forbidden, but i would prefer a pure html/css solution

Comment: i also tried table-cell, but either the cell width is less than 100% or the image is fully shown [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQ4wp/5/)

Comment: a close solution is given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JQ4wp/6/), which seems to work for arbitrary sized images with the same aspect ratio. I need this for images of any size.

Answer (score 1):

i know it's using javascript but there is no pure HTML/CSS solution for this, unless you go the background-image way.

- give the container a position: relative
- give the image a position: absolute, top: 50%;
- give the image, (using javascript) a marginTop of half its height

http://jsfiddle.net/yvrwL/

Css:

```
img {
    top: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
#inner{
    position: relative;
}
```

Javascript

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $img = $('img');
    $img.css({
        'margin-top': ($img.height() / -2) + 'px'
    });
});
```

Comment: close to what i want. Unfortunatly needs reload after window resize.

Comment: wrap it in `$(window).resize(function(){ ... });` then... `jQuery(function($){ $(window).resize(function(){ var $img = $('img'); $img.css({marginTop: ($img.height() / 2) + 'px'}); }); });`

Answer (score 0):

Change the image to a background image. This gives you more control.

```
.tux { 
background-image: url('tux.gif');
background-position: center; 
background-size: cover;
}
```

You can control the size and position with `background-position` and `background-size`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this does what you want. 
check this out:

```
#inner{
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
img{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

js:

```
$('#inner img').load(function(){
    $(this).css({
        marginTop: -1/2 * $(this).height()
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taxellool/x43L9/)

Comment: close, but not too good: when you make the area very narrow, the image flows out of the div.